# statistical graphs with as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, graphics, statistics

Does anyone know of a good library for making statistical graphs, such as histograms and box plots for as3. I've been looking but so far I haven't found anything really useful.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for flare:

http://flare.prefuse.org/